# Comment Overflow

Tags: bug, status-declined, comments, design

I previously reported a layout bug in travel SE that the comments overflows the network posts in the right panel.

I checked some other sites and I can't find such an issue other than in travel SE.

But now when I checked stack overflow, I saw the same issue there.

## In travel SE

[image]

## In Stack Overflow

[image]

## Link to travel SE meta post

[Comment Overflow](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4467/57836)

> Browser : Chrome Canary 60.0.3104.0 for Android

Comment: Is Canary still a dev/experimental build or is that now mainstream?

Comment: It would help I think if you link to specific question that for sure demonstrates the issue. You're not zoomed in or out, right? Because most sizes of text seems off.

Comment: Something in your browser is changing the text size, and inherently changing the width of the containers too. There's not much we can do about that. We don't officially support the weird things mobile browsers do to the page.

Comment: Chrome canary stable release @rene

Comment: @rene this is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44584531/javascript-why-cant-i-access-the-directory-in-browser-on-mac

Comment: @animuson only comments have the problem. Posts and bounty notice didn't have this issue

Comment: That page renders correctly in a desktop browser and in the mobile view, so there's nothing to fix. As previously stated, we don't officially support mobile browsers on the desktop view of the site. That's why there is a separate desktop view and mobile view. Using the desktop view on mobile, you're bound to find oddities as mobile devices use very different methods of rendering.

Comment: I have an issue in mobile view which I already reported. Some parts are black shaded. OK I will try after clearing the browser cache and other things

Comment: @sagar canary is a nightly development build and is often broken. SE won't support a product that is broken that often.

Comment: It's not about the browser, it's about your device. You are browsing the full site theme on a mobile device. Problems like this are totally expected. No bug here. If you want better design, use the mobile theme. If for some reason the site didn't identify your device as mobile, click the "mobile" link in the footer and you'll see the mobile version of the site, meant for, well, mobile devices.

Comment: @ShadowWizard my default view is mobile and I changed it to full site coz in mobile view, only some part renders and other parts are covered with a huge black box.

Comment: @SagarV fair enough, but like I said - this is not a bug, the full site theme is not supposed to be viewed on mobile device.

Answer (score 1):

As is [officially stated](https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel#TOC-Reporting-Dev-channel-and-Canary-build-problems) and [discussed on Super User](https://superuser.com/a/582320/688600), Chrome Canary is a very fast-forward beta test channel.

> **Canary build**: Canary builds are the bleeding edge. Released daily, this build **has not been tested or used**, it's released as soon as it's built. Because there's no guarantee that it will even run in some cases, it uses it's own profile and settings, and can be run side by side another Chrome channel.  By default, it also reports crashes and usage statistics to Google (you can disable this on the download page).

It contains untested feature and tweaks. It's not even known whether they will stay in any later stable releases. Any bug on a web page, including Stack Exchange, may be caused by Chrome Canary. As I've tested by myself, this bug does not exist in Chrome Stable 57.0.2987.133 for Windows.

On mobile using desktop view, it does, but why do you think a perfect layout from a desktop site on mobile is necessary? As per [animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525)'s comment, that page renders correctly in a desktop browser and in the mobile view, so there's nothing to fix. As previously stated, Stack Exchange don't officially support mobile browsers on the desktop view of the site. That's why there is a separate desktop view and mobile view. Using the desktop view on mobile, you're bound to find oddities as mobile devices use very different methods of rendering.

Comment: I don't think Canary is the issue, i.e. this will happen with any browser. The issue here is viewing full site theme on mobile device.

Comment: @Sha not sure about Android but it doesn't happen on iOS Chrome (or Safari)