# Footer extending in the stackexchange.com in mobile web view

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web, stackexchange.com, footer

The newly introduced footer is extending in the https://stackexchange.com site in mobile web view.

Screenshot for reference:

[image: Footer length issue]

Comment: Leave it alone. Desktop sites are not intended for mobile views.

Comment: @iBug that is one page for desktop and mobile. there is no mobile page available for list of sites

Answer (score -1):

The [Stack Exchange Portal](https://stackexchange.com/) is a desktop site. It does not have a mobile view by far.

Desktop browsers render pages differently than mobiles, and as per *animuson* ♦'s [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297321/comment-overflow/297335#comment964513_297321) and [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297321/comment-overflow/297335#comment964518_297321),

> We don't officially support the weird things mobile browsers do to the page.

> Using the desktop view on mobile, you're bound to find oddities as mobile devices use very different methods of rendering.

Let's wait for SE to develop a mobile portal.